# Minecraft - "Couldn't unpack natives"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Everytime I try to launch the game (v1.7.4), it starts out normal, then starts getting timeouts half way in while trying to connect to the server, then just says it's assuming that the local file is good, after that I get this:

```
[17:13:35 ERROR]: Couldn't unpack natives!
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at net.minecraft.launcher.GameLauncher.unpackNatives(GameLauncher.java:469) ~[launcher.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.launcher.GameLauncher.launchGame(GameLauncher.java:213) [launcher.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.launcher.GameLauncher.onDownloadJobFinished(GameLauncher.java:619) [launcher.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:120) [launcher.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: Try re-downloading Minecraft. 
Try running the launcher in Administrator mode.

Comment: Already tried that :\

Comment: Just wondering, is there more to this error log?
Minecraft can't download it's resource files. Perhaps there's something wrong with the destination folder. 
Delete the Minecraft directory instead of re-downloading.

Comment: I tried all of that before, and there is nothing else to really show on the rest of the error log, it just says, "Trying to download..." "Finished downloading...", but it's working now, didn't change anything whatsoever, so I don't know what the problem was :/ only thing now is that it takes about 10 minutes to launch the game

Comment: Well, actually this shouldn't be marked duplicate because the question this one is linked to doesn't have the answer to this specific question. Nominating for reopening until that one does..

Comment: @JeffreyLin that's not how closing works. You can't ask the same question again and again until an answer you like is posted.

Comment: @kotekzot The answer to this question can't be found there though.